# How to plot a bar chart using chart.js and Ajax in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to display a bar chart using chart.js and C# code with an Ajax call in my application using the below script and code. The chart is not displaying. The code is in C# and I am writing the UI code in aspx file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home.asmx/GetMonthtlyInspectionData",
        data: jsonData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var data = response.d.Datas;
            var label = response.d.Labels;
            let ctx = $("#barChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
            ctx.height = 130;
            new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: label,
                    type: 'bar',
                    defaultFontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    datasets: [{
                        data: data,
                        label: "Approved Request",
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        borderColor: 'transparent',
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        pointStyle: 'circle',
                        pointRadius: 5,
                        pointBorderColor: '#847DFA',
                        pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: !0,
                    maintainAspectRatio: true,
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        titleFontSize: 12,
                        titleFontColor: '#fff',
                        bodyFontColor: '#fff',
                        backgroundColor: '#000',
                        titleFontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        bodyFontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        cornerRadius: 3,
                        intersect: false,
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                        position: 'top',
                        labels: {
                            usePointStyle: true,
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        },

                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            display: true,
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false,
                                drawBorder: true
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Month'
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false,
                                drawBorder: true
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Inspection Request Count'
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Below is my aspx.cs code -

```
public List<HomeModel> GetMonthtlyCaseData()
{
    List<HomeModel> t = new List<HomeModel>();
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnCase"].ConnectionString;

    using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(conn))
    {
        string myQuery = "Select  count(CaseNo),to_char(to_date(CaseDt, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),'Month') from t_case_detail group by CaseNo,CaseDt ";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = myQuery;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cn.Open();
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                HomeModel tsData = new HomeModel();
                tsData.month = dr["CaseDt"].ToString();
                tsData.requestNo = dr["CaseNo"].ToString();
                t.Add(tsData);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: please format the code properly. as you can see the method is not fully highlighted. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow/51145

Comment: @stealthyninja, thanks for editing the same.

Comment: @mybrave, pls suggest now.

Comment: Any experts there to suggest the solution?waiting since yesterday.

Comment: I would split the troubleshooting into two parts. 1. verify that the API gives you expected result 2. review javascript code for errors and use browser developer tools to debug success function

Comment: please give the solution

Comment: Sorry but it is not working this way. SO is not doing your homeworks. Even if somebody provide you working sample (there are plenty of them already) then you need to be able to troubleshoot your own code.

Comment: @mybrave, asked the question coz i have done all homeworks from my side buddy. tried every solution but didn't worked till then. Only after that i have posted the question. However we can end the discussion here as i have got the solution from different source. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: That's great. Sometimes we need to do more investigation and even answer the questions ourselves. Feel free to post your solution here too or reference the solution you found elsewhere.